# can we set the functionality of snooze alarm in our app as iphone's built in alarm?

Tags: ios, iphone

i am developing alarm application. And i want to set the functionality of **snooze alarm** for specific time. As the iPhone's system alarm functionality that is "when we switch off the phone after setting the alarm".And it works like (tap to snooze or press any button to snooze) And slide to unlock the phone.

i want **set** tap to snooze instead of **slide to snooze Functionality**.

[image: Here Is my output screen]

**Source Code:**

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = date;
NSLog(@"Notification will be shown on: %@",localNotification.fireDate);

localNotification.alertBody = @"Time to wake up";
localNotification.alertAction = @"Snooze";

localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Comment: so whats stoping you from doing that? i say its a good idea, go ahead and add that to your app.:)

Comment: @XCodeMonkey Plz See my updated screen Shot and code..!!